# Cambiar el campo referencia de una llave foránea en mysql

Tags: django, sqlite, modelorelacional

Existe alguna manera cambiar el campo al que referencia una llave foránea?
Tengo estas dos tablas

```
Persona:
Id = int PK
Nombre = char
Apellido = char
Cédula = int UNIQUE

Tienda:
Id = int PK
Localización = char
Dueño = int
FOREIGN KEY ("Id") references "Persona" ("id") on_delete = cascade
```

En el caso de que ya tenga registros en ambas tablas, por ejemplo

Persona:

Id-------nombre.---------Apellido.-----------Cedula

1. ```
    Juan.       Pérez.       1000
   ```
2. ```
    Andrés.    Martínez.     2000
   ```

Tienda:

Id.------Localización.-------Dueño

1. ```
    Norte.          1
   ```
2. ```
     Sur.           2
   ```

Existe alguna manera de cambiar la referencia de esta llave foránea (dueño)
Que no se refiera al campo Id, sino al campo Cédula? También es un campo unico, y es más fácil para referenciar para el usuario

Pdta: Intente de expresarlo lo más simple posible, por esta razón hay la menor cantidad de código posibke

Comment: O guardas id, o guardas cedulas... no podes guardar las dos cosas en el mismo campo.. si no, como vas a saber magicamente si el campo tiene un id o una cedula? y no, no vale decir que la cedula es mas grande, porque el id puede crecer hasta ahi... Ahora, con esta informacion, como sabrias que es?

Comment: Hay q considerar antes si existen modulos o componentes dl sistema q ya interpretan (para almacenamiento, cruces, visualización)  la columna `Dueño` como identificador de fila. Es importante porque cambiar el concepto (como se interpreta) dicha columna, implica cambios en las partes que ya la.usan; o de lo contrario el resto dl sistema será inconsistente. Ej: Si ya hay un proceso de ingreso de datos para `Tienda` que basado en una cédula consulta la tabla `Persona` por columna `Cédula` para obtener valor de columna `id` y almacenarlo en columna `Dueño`;hay que modificar dicho proceso tambien

Comment: Considerado el anterioir comentario (modelo relacional) si es.posible alterar la foranea. Requiere: 1) Crear una nueva columna `ced_dueno` en `Persona` para almacenar temporalmente la cedula del dueño 2) Cruzar `Persona` con `Tienda` usando `Tienda.Dueno=Persona.Id` y actualizar la nueva columna `ced_dueno=Persona.cedula` 3) Eliminar la actual foránea) 4) Actualizar `Tienda.Dueno=Tienda.ced_dueno` 5) Crear nueva foránea `Tienda(Dueno) references Persona(Cedula)` 5) Eliminar columna `ced_dueno`. Todo lo anterior con sistema en mantenimiento. `PERO AFECTA A TODOS LOS DEMAS MODULOS` como ya dije

Comment: Eso es una respuesta amigo, si llegue a pensar en mk cabeza lo que dijiste, pero pensé que así yo creará otra columna y creará  la relación, el constraint no me dejaría eliminar la columna. En cuanto a las precauciones que me dices, lo tengo muy en claro, solo que, como te digo, teniendo la referencia así como está, en un proyecto más grande que es el que estoy realizando, tengo que hacer una consulta adicional para poder saber, por ejemplo, la cédula en persona, y ese proceso es el que quiero evitar, pero dale amigo, te agradecería que lo pusieras como respuesta